# Showing that this equation for z holds

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assuming that the function $z = z(x, y)$ has continuous partial derivatives and $\phi = \phi(s)$
is continuously differentiable, show that the following holds
$$x^2z_x − xyz_y + y^2 = 0, \text{where } z = y^2/3x + \phi(xy)$$
I'm not too sure where to start with the function ϕ within this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just straightforward computation. Since $\phi$ is a function of a single variable,
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \phi(xy) = \phi_x(xy) \cdot y = y \cdot \phi'(xy)$$
So just use this to compute $z_x$ and $z_y$ and plug it in. It works out. Whatever the mysterious $\phi$ function is, the terms containing it cancel out.

Comment: I see what you're talking about and have eliminated the function from the equation, thank you for the help. I am however left with y$^2$(1-x)/3 and I'm not too sure how to equate this to zero. Have I just messed up my working or do I still have more to do?

Comment: Looks like an arithmetic error to me. Did you multiply $z_y$ by $xy$? I had $-y^2/3$ appear in the $z_x$ term and $-2y^2/3$ appear in the $z_y$ term, which add up to cancel the given $y^2$.